# Chrubuntu 14.04 WINE install unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies, aptitude

Okay, I understand that there have been quite a few solutions to this problem. None of them have worked for me. To explain my conundrum I shall post the output of "sudo aptitude install wine1.7". EDIT: added result of sudo aptitude upgrade

`user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude install wine1.7
[sudo] password for user: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-horai-umefont{a} fonts-unfonts-core{a} gnome-exe-thumbnailer{a} 
  icoutils{a} libcapi20-3{a} libgnutls26{a} libodbc1{a} libosmesa6{a} 
  odbcinst{a} odbcinst1debian2{a} p7zip{a} unixodbc{a} wine-gecko2.34{a} 
  wine-mono4.5.2{a} wine1.7{b} wine1.7-amd64{a} winetricks{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 123 MB of archives. After unpacking 359 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.31-0ubuntu1~ppa1) which is a virtual package.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     wine1.7 [Not Installed]                            
2)     wine1.7-amd64 [Not Installed]                      

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
3)     winetricks recommends wine                         
4)     wine-gecko2.34 recommends wine1.5-amd64            


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] 
user@chrubuntu:~$ sudo aptitude update
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease                                  
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease                                       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates InRelease                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                          
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security InRelease              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease                        
Ign http://de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                    
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release.gpg
Get: 1 http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg [316 B]
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates Release                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security Release                
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Sources/DiffIndex           
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages                  
Hit http://de.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted Sources   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted Sources         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main amd64 Packages                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe Sources                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse Sources                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main amd64 Packages                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/universe amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/multiverse amd64 Packages                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main Sources                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe Sources                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse Sources                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/universe amd64 Packages            
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main fjsidojf Packages                      
  404  Not Found
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main Sources                      
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i38 Packages                           
  404  Not Found
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe Sources                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/main amd64 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/universe amd64 Packages           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic-security/multiverse amd64 Packages         
Fetched 316 B in 10s (30 B/s)                                                   
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9A6CA8A7C8C782DE
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-fjsidojf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-updates/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-fjsidojf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-fjsidojf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/dists/utopic/Release: Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-fjsidojf/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/joe-yasi/yasi/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-fjsidojf/Packages: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/joe-yasi/yasi/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-i38/Packages: 404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache

W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to update the package lists to correct these missing files`

Any further attempts to solve would return the same. I have tried most alternatives, including the software center and [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa). Help would be appreciated. Thank You. It is good to finally join the Ubuntu community.

P.S If needed, just ask for additional information.

Comment: I'll check those solutions.

Comment: None of the solutions worked. I did get some error in the upgrade attempts. They were added to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing fjsidojf frmo your sources?

And adding i386 support might help for most chrubuntu users.

```
sudo apt --add-architecture i386
```

Wine installed out of the box for me after that.